# ApexCharts scatterplot with categories on the x-axis and each category has multiple y-values

Tags: vuejs3, apexcharts, quasar

I am trying to create a scatterplot with ApexCharts using Vue3. My chart will have several different categories on the x-axis and each category will have multiple y-values. However, I cannot figure out how to properly format my data to achieve this. The desired look of the chart should resemble a bunch of data points stacked vertically for each category. (not directly on top of each other, they y-values are all slightly different)

After referring to the documentation here: https://apexcharts.com/docs/series/

I've tried a few different approaches to formatting my data.

I've tried this way:

```
   let series = [
      {
        name: "Name 1",
        data: [10, NaN, NaN],
      },
      {
        name: "Name 1",
        data: [20, NaN, NaN],
      },
      {
        name: "Name 2",
        data: [NaN, 30, NaN],
      },
      {
        name: "Name 2",
        data: [NaN, 35, NaN],
      },
      {
        name: "Name 3",
        data: [NaN, NaN, 45],
      },
      {
        name: "Name 3",
        data: [NaN, NaN, 55],
      },
    ];

let chartOptions = {
   xaxis: {
      categories: ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"]
```

The result here will not allow me to add more than one value for each category.

Next, I tried like this:

```
    let series = [
      {
        name: "name1",
        data: [
          { x: "cat1", y: 54 },
          { x: "cat1", y: 60 },
          { x: "cat2", y: 66 },
          { x: "cat2", y: 70 },
        ],
      },
       {
         name: "name2",
         data: [
           { x: "cat3", y: 33 },
           { x: "cat3", y: 40 },
           { x: "cat4", y: 54 },
           { x: "cat4", y: 58 },
         ],
       },

   let chartOptions = {
   xaxis: {
      type: "category"
```

The result here was two categories on the xaxis that say "cat1" with each having one data point from name1 and name2

I haven't been able to find any examples of an Apex scatterplot that show this particular case of category data with multiple y-values and I'm just not sure what the issue is with my formatting of the data. I have been able to achieve the desired outcome, but only if I use paired numeric values or a datetime on the x-axis.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple points for the same category if you avoid duplicates within the same series.

```js
let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'name1',
    data: [
      { x: 'cat1', y: 54 },
      { x: 'cat2', y: 66 },
      { x: 'cat3', y: 33 },
      { x: 'cat4', y: 54 }
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'name2',
    data: [
      { x: 'cat1', y: 60 },
      { x: 'cat2', y: 70 },
      { x: 'cat3', y: 40 },
      { x: 'cat4', y: 58 }
    ]
  }],
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: 'scatter'
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: 'category'
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

If you tweak your data and add explicit categories to the `xaxis`, you can get this:

```js
let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'name1',
    data: [
      [1, 54],
      [1, 60],
      [2, 66],
      [2, 70]
    ]
  }, {
    name: 'name2',
    data: [
      [3, 33],
      [3, 40],
      [4, 54],
      [4, 58]
    ]
  }],
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    type: 'scatter'
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4']
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm trying to find a way to plot data that would have multiple Y values for each category. For example, one series might have only one X-value (a category in this case) and then have multiple Y values. Similar to your result except the dots stacked on top of each other would all be the same color (or series)

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do. I edited my answer. Is it the expected result?

Comment: Yes, that's it! I'm assuming that when you give the pair of numbers the "1" is the first category in your category list and so on....? I didn't see that anywhere in the docs.

But, thanks for the help through. It's much appreciated!

Comment: I think it is not documented because the maker of ApexCharts did not identify this very specific need. Thus, this solution is not standard and you will have problems if you interact with the legend...